# CSS positioning help required for a jQuery plugin - jsfiddle example provided

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, positioning

I'm using the following plugin to create a sliding panel: http://samuelgarneau.com/lab/slidebox/

But when I put it on my site, it seems to be in a fixed position, rather than scrolling along with the rest of the site. I've made it up in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cYrJB/

I want the "companies" tab to scroll with the site - but is just sticks to the top. I think it might be interacting with the fullscreen image plugin I'm using...

I've tried playing with it, and no luck - wondering if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Works for me! What browser are you using (I use Chrome)? I'll investigate the code a bit and see if I can see anything wrong.

Comment: Do you want the 'Companies' to stay at the very top of the page or the top of the current view?

Comment: @Fred/Heather doesn't work for me and I use Chrome too!? I'm not familiar with the plug in. You've got a lot going on in the CSS. I'd try to work from the original example on Samuel's site and modify it a bit at a time until it breaks (or doesn't :))

Comment: @El Ronnoco I didn't quite understand what `Heathwalker` was hoping to achieve, but now I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the companies button and content within the #realBody DIV. The scroll bar for the site is actually on the realBody DIV, not on the body tag. The body never scrolls due to the fullscreenr plugin. [Corrected code](http://jsfiddle.net/cYrJB/2/)

Comment: Sorry if I explained this poorly all you kind helpful people. Dark Falcon fixed it for me. I have had to remove a bit of padding - but now goes up with the top bar. Thank you all so very much!